# Using listdir realpath abspath with symbolic links

Tags: python, realpath

Something that I don't understand :
In a shell :

```
mkdir -p /tmp/toto/titi/tutu    
touch /tmp/toto/tata    
ln -s /tmp/toto/tata /tmp/toto/titi/tutu/     
python
```

Then in python:

```
import os
zeList = os.listdir("/tmp/toto/titi/tutu/")
print os.path.realpath(zeList[0])
 >'/tata' 
print os.path.abspath(zeList[0])
 >'/tata'
```

The expected result should be : /tmp/toto/tata (or /tmp/toto/titi/tutu/tata). 
Can anyone explain this result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns *base filenames*, not full paths:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir("/tmp/toto/titi/tutu/")
['tata']
```

Without a path, the file is then considered relative to the *current working directory*:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7'
>>> os.path.realpath('tata')
'/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/tata'
```

Join the filename with the path first:

```
testdir = "/tmp/toto/titi/tutu/"
zeList = [os.path.join(testdir, fname) for fname in os.listdir(testdir)]
```

Now the symbolic link is properly replaced:

```
>>> testdir = "/tmp/toto/titi/tutu/"
>>> zeList = [os.path.join(testdir, fname) for fname in os.listdir(testdir)]
>>> print os.path.realpath(zeList[0])
/private/tmp/toto/tata
>>> print os.path.abspath(zeList[0])
/tmp/toto/titi/tutu/tata
```

Answer (score 0):

`listdir` returns filenames, not paths. Therefore you are passing a relative path to `realpath` which is interpreted relative to your working directory `/`.

Use `os.path.realpath(os.path.join(..., zeList[0]))` for correct results.